# Create and set an element of a Pandas DataFrame to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that I'm creating row-by-row (I know, I know, it's not Pandorable/Pythonic..). I'm creating elements using *.loc* like so

```
output.loc[row_id, col_id]
```

and I'd like to set this value to an empty list, [].

```
output.loc[row_id, col_id] = []
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying the size of my keys and values do not match (Pandas thinks I'm trying to set values *with* not *to* an iterable).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure two things:

1. there is precisely one entry for that loc,
2. the column has dtype object (actually, on testing this seems not to be an issue).

---

A hacky way to do this is to use a Series with []:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df.loc[[0], 'A'] = pd.Series([[]])

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
    A  B
0  []  2
1   3  4
```

*pandas doesn't really want you use `[]` as elements because it's usually not so efficient and makes aggregations more complicated (and un-cythonisable).*

---

In general you don't want to build up DataFrames cell-by-cell, there is (almost?) always a better way.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why'd you put 0 in a list in "df.loc[[0], 'A']"?

Comment: So assignment is done to a Series rather than a single entry/value, that's the "trick"/hack here!

Comment: "In general you don't want to build up DataFrames cell-by-cell, there is (almost?) always a better way."

That depends on your use case. I use a DataFrame as the fundamental data structure in an app I've written, and that sets dataframes cell-by-cell all the time. This is not an issue in an interacive app since here, processing time is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @Thriveth "In general" :)

Comment: Isn't it a bit of an unnecessary hindrance that the only solution is "hacky"? Not criticising the answer, more pandas itself. I get the feeling there's is often a logic of "we would never need to do this way, so no one else should either," when pandas is involved. Yet there absolutely are reasons why someone would need to do things this way, the fact that someone is asking a question with several positive votes is proof of that.

Comment: I guess what I would like to know is, what is the "better" way to do something like this?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon The main take away is "don't"! If you're needing to do something like this there's almost certainly a better way (an alternative approach where you don't need to do this). Python objects such as lists inside a pandas DataFrame/Series is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Is there anywhere we can ask for tips on something like coding in a better way or using alternate approaches like this? Since as far as I can tell, it would be a bit open-ended and more like a discussion, and thus not recommended for stackoverflow. Is it okay if I ask here (this is just one case where I felt like I wanted to use something like putting lists in a dataframe).

Comment: I'm using dataframes to hold "catalogues" of astrophysical objects. I would like to crossreference between two catalogues; but one catalog can contain multiple potential entries for one object. So I want to have a column in dataframe A that contains all the ids of objects in dataframe B that could match the object in A. This is just one case where I wanted to do this, maybe not the best, I don't know. Is the answer just not to use pandas then?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon I think the answer is use multiple columns e.g. a MultiIndex. Or something else to join against. You can workaround this without including lists in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 9):

You can use *pd.at* instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['B'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['A'] = None
df.at[1, 'A'] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

When you use `pd.loc`, pandas thinks you are interacting with a set of rows. So if you try to assign an array using `pd.loc`, pandas will try to match each element of an array with a corresponding element accessed by `pd.loc`, hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by MishaTeplitskiy works when the index label is 0. More generally, if you want to assign an array x to an element of a DataFrame df with row r and column c, you can use:

```
df.loc[[r], c] = pd.Series([x], index = [r])
```