# How to assign a list to a particular condition in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to assign a list to a particular condition in a dataframe. But, i am getting an error as "*ValueError: Length of values(21) does not match length of index(1)*"

my query is  : **df[df["column_name"]==some_value]["column_name"] = list**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to update an individual value to hold a list:

```python
lst = [7,8,9]
condition = df["column_name"]==2
df.loc[condition, "column_name"] = pd.Series([lst], index=df[condition].index)
```

Sample input:

```
   column_name  b
0            1  4
1            2  5
2            3  6
```

Output:

```
  column_name  b
0           1  4
1   [7, 8, 9]  5
2           3  6
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34078423/18135454) as well.